# User ternary operator for 3 possible outcomes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator

I want to write a ternary operator based on the following;

```
var statusJSON = {
    '- Select -': '',
    'Active': true,
    'Inactive': false
};
```

Currently I have

```
statusFlag: $('#statusFlag').val() == 'true' ? true : false
```

This works fine for `true` and `false` values, but does not handle the 3rd condition (i.e. empty `""`)

How do I handle the same ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how the object relates to the conditional operator. If ` $('#statusFlag').val()` returns one of the property names, you'd use `statusJSON[$('#statusFlag').val()]`. Is that what you actually want?

Comment: That would need a quaternary operator.

Comment: This seems like a job for a lookup/find method

Comment: possibly better use `'- Select -' : 'empty', ` and `statusFlag: $('#statusFlag').val()`

Answer (score 14):

```
statusFlag: $('#statusFlag').val() == 'true' ? true : 
            $('#statusFlag').val() == '' ? 'empty' : false
```

You can just add multiple conditions like this:

```
a ? b : (c ? d : e)
```

`()` aren't necessary, but in my opinion, they improve readability when you write it without linebreaks.

This means:

```
if(a){
    b
}else{
    if(c){
        d
    }else{
        e
    }
}
```

So, basically, you're nesting another ternary operator in the `else` clause of the previous one. You can go as far as you'd like with this:

```
a ? b :   // if(a) then `b`
c ? d :   // else, if(c) then `d`
e ? f :   // else, if(e) then `f`
g ? h :   // else, if(g) then `h`
i ? j : k // else, if(i) then `j`, else `k`
```

Comment: Very well explained.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Try to nest the `ternary` operator,

```
statusFlag: $('#statusFlag').val() == 'true' ?
          true : $('#statusFlag').val() == 'false' ? false : "empty";
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use 2 conditionals in the ternary expression, something like:

```
value = (condition1) ? a : (condition2) ? c : d;
```

Your case:

```
statusFlag: $('#statusFlag').val() == 'true' ? true : 
        $('#statusFlag').val() == '' ? 'empty' : false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `statusJSON` as a lookup table:

```
var val = $('#statusFlag').val();
… statusFlag: val in statusJSON ? statusJSON[val] : false /*or whatever*/
```

If you're sure that only the three values do occur, or are fine with an `undefined` outcome otherwise, you might as well just use

```
… statusFlag: statusJSON[$('#statusFlag').val()]
```